# Mootools Click Event Problem

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

This peace of code works for the first click. but then it seems to not be able to get new ID from next click. the idea behind it is to show one piece of a form and with click on a button it hides first and shows second part. any idea what im doing wrong?
i guess it has something to do with "this" but from my understanding it should get the id  from the second link also.

```
        window.addEvent('domready', function() 
            {
            $('page_2').slide('hide');
            $('page_3').slide('hide');
            $('page_4').slide('hide');
            $('page_5').slide('hide');
            var togglePrefix = 'toggle_', boxPrefix = 'page_', emptyPrefix = '';
            var links = $('submit_box').getElements('a');
            links.addEvent('click', function(e)
                {
                e.stop();
                var id = $(this.get('id').replace(togglePrefix,emptyPrefix));
                var id_new = parseInt($(this).get('id').replace(togglePrefix, emptyPrefix)) + 1; 
                var next = ('page_'+id_new);
                var id_old = $(this.get('id').replace(togglePrefix,boxPrefix));
                $(id_old).set('slide', {duration: 'long', transition: 'linear'});
                $(id_old).slide('out');
                $(next).slide('in');
                });
            });
```

the html follows  this pattern:

```
<div id="page_1">

    <div id="inhalt-gewinn">
      <div id="gewinn_bild"></div>
      <div id="gewinn_form">
          <form id="gewinnspiel" name="gewinnspiel" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>">
              <div id="input_box">
                  <div><input type="radio" name="frage1" value="Kamille" /><span>Kamille</span></div>
                  <div><input type="radio" name="frage1" value="Kaktus" /><span>Kaktus</span></div>
                  <div><input type="radio" name="frage1" value="Krokus" /><span>Krokus</span></div>

              </div>
              <div id="submit_box"><a id="toggle_1" class="frage">nächste Frage...</a></div>

      </div>
      <div id="gewinn_werbung"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the example, you've got a bunch of divs with id page_1, page_2 and so on. In every div is a div with the id "submit_box". When you wrote `$('submit_box').getElements('a')` it will add the event only to the first div cause an id has to be unique. You cant have more then one element with a unique id in the page. So to get your example work change the id to a classname and use $$('div.submit_box a').

Answer (score 0):

The use of ID´s multiple times on the page ruined the code!
After fixing this  it  worked  fine

Comment: There has got to be a better way of writing this.  Please make a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) and maybe someone can help steer you correctly.